# Shuffle inside a ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, foreach

If a do a very simple ForEach loop I'm able to use a shuffle parameter to shuffle the things inside.

Something linke this:

```
 var plays: [Play] = playData
    
    var body: some View {
NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(plays.shuffled()) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        PlayDetailView(play: item)
                    } label: {
                        PlayCard(play: item)
                            .padding(.vertical, 7)
                    }
                }
            }
```

But when I use an Environment object and call something different inside the loop, I don't have the option to shuffle things.

Can someone point me in the right direction to **shuffle the results of the following loops**?

```
var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160), spacing: 15)]) {
            ForEach(0..<modelData.stories.count, id: \.self) { item in
                if modelData.stories[item].featured == true {
                    NavigationLink {
                        StoryDetails(story: modelData.stories[item])
                    } label: {
                        GeneralCard(story: modelData.stories[item])
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the ModelData:

```
struct Story: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var featured: Bool
    var paid: Bool
    var featuredImage: String
    var bigImage: String
    var text: [String]
    var category: Category

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to post the code for your `ModelData`, but it needs to be `Identifiable`. Using `id: \.self` will prevent the reordering as the ForEach can get confused.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb. I'm reading the info. I just added the ModelData. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can’t use indicies or \.self in the ForEach View with dynamic data, you have to supply the identifiable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a closed range and iterating over it, accesing the data by index. Thats in it self not a good practice. It would be easier if you iterate over the collection itself.

```
ForEach(modelData.stories.shuffled()) { story in
            if story.featured == true {
                NavigationLink {
                    StoryDetails(story: story)
                } label: {
                    GeneralCard(story: story)
                }
            }
```

You don´t need the initializer with the id here. Your `Story` items allready conform to `Identifiable`.

Comment: Thanks, @burnsi that's the first thing I tried, but Xcode is telling me that I'm "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call". That's when I tried the other option. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @DiegoAlcu Please edit your question and add the code where this error Message appears. This code compiles fine for me (exept the 2 Views not included in your example).

Comment: I had a little error, it's working now as you suggested. Thanks.